# How do I replace duplicate data with random data of same length in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to replace duplicate alphanumeric data with random alphanumeric data of same length.

Current data in column:

```
LY00CMY297
7Q7GC4J170
7Q7GC4J170(Duplicate Record)
7Q7GC4J170(Duplicate Record)
2MQ493J561
2MQ493J648
```

Expected result:

```
LY00CMY297
7Q7GC4J170
  ***(Need random alphanumeric data of length 10)
  ***(Need random alphanumeric data of length 10)
2MQ493J561
2MQ493J648
```

Could someone help?

Comment: What have *you* tried so far, both to find the duplicate rows (of which there are lots of examples on SO on how to do), and create your random string.

Comment: Could those `random` data be duplicated with other data in your column, for e.g in your case could those be `2MQ493J561`, `2MQ493J648` or `LY00CMY297`?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach No, The requirement is to make column data unique

Comment: If the column needs to be unique, why doesn't it have a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT/INDEX`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
;with cte as (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ColumnName order by ColumnName) rn,right(convert(varchar(36), newid()),10) as New from TableName
) 

update cte set ColumnName=New 
where rn>1;
```

NewID() function will always creare Unique ID.

Comment: Will need to make sure that the new generated ID isn't already present on another record, although chances are slim.

Comment: @RedDevil , I'm getting hyphen symbol in converted data eg: A9722DF8-F

Comment: @RedDevil , Cool!!

Comment: Just as a side note, the OP does have characters after `F` in their sample data; this method would only use the characters `0-9` and `A-F`. Might well not be a problem, but i thought worth noting